# CTC Loss InvalidArgumentError: sequence_length(b) <= time

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am running into this error while trying to use tf.nn.ctc_loss through keras (ctc_batch_cost):

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): sequence_length(4) <= 471

According to the documentation for tf.nn.ctc_loss, Input requirements are:

> sequence_length(b) <= time for all b
>
> max(labels.indices(labels.indices[:, 1] == b, 2))   <=
>   sequence_length(b) for all b.

I am having a hard time understanding what this means-- what is `b` and what is `sequence_length(b)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case `b` is each example in a minibatch. `sequence_length(b)` is the number of time stamps you have for that example. This is specified in the `sequence_length` argument passed to `tf.nn.ctc_loss` which is a 1-d tensor of sequence lengths.

Comment: What does `time` mean in this case? I get it that `sequence_length(b) <= time for all b` means that the sequence length of each example in a minibatch should be less than or equal to `time`. Care to give an example?

Comment: sequence_length should be a tensor representing the sizes of each sequence in your minibatch. time is the second dimension of your data tensor (which should be ordered as [batch, time, ...]). This just says that the sequence length of each example should be less than the maximum size of the time dimension

Comment: So if I pass a `Tensor` with a reduced `time` dimension due to the layers it has gone through (e.g. convolution with max pooling followed by lstm) to `ctc_loss`, should the `sequence_length` be less that that `time` dimension?

Comment: yes. The sequence length for each example should refer to what the time dimension would be if you only had that example in the minibatch

Comment: Shouldn't the `sequence_length` for each example just be equal to the time dimension? In what cases would I want the `sequence_length` be less than the time dimension?

Comment: What if one example has 10 time steps and another only has 5, and you still want to minibatch your computation?

Comment: Does sequence_length(b) refer to the sequence length of the target or the sequence length of the input (being the number of timesteps)?

Comment: Length of the input sequence.

Comment: I'm confused. I checked this [test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/ctc_loss_op_test.py) for `ctc_loss` and the sequence lengths are attached to the targets. Is it just a coincidence that the number of time steps is equal to the length of each target?